# How to produce JSON to Kafka broker from Javascript running on a browser, with least ceremony?

Tags: javascript, rest, apache-kafka, kafka-rest

I have a javascript application which is extremely small, I want to consume my Kafka broker from the javascript application (only a single pushJasonBatch function). I'd rather not deal with installing additional tools as much as I can.

I don't use Confluent.
So: How to produce JSON to Kafka broker from Javascript running on a browser, with least ceremony?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you don't want to run something line the [Kafka Rest Proxy](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest) on the backend (for which, BTW, you don't need the Confluent Platform) then the simplest choice is kafka-node:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/kafka-node

Comment: +1 for the REST proxy. It's open source, and whilst it's included as part of Confluent Platform, can also be used standalone with another Kafka cluster.